# Best solution for a room with slightly different floor height

Tags: flooring

I recently purchased a new home and the previous owners had done some modifications.

Firstly they had made a car port with an upstairs bedroom, then they enclosed the car port and extended the kitchen into that space. Now the original floor space and the new extended floor space have a slightly different floor height with the extended part being approx 3-5cm higher. There is a ramp at this area which I want to eliminate. Preferably lowering the floor of the extension.

I can see this is going to be a pain and a messy job but what exactly is my best option here?

My initial thought would be to break the floor in that area, lay new concrete and self level. In my head this is a massive job though. Has anyone dealt with such a task before? Any advice?

Comment: What is your budget? I foresee many headaches and many thousands of dollars involved in this plan. Some questions to consider: How will you remove the busted concrete? Thru the house in wheelbarrow? How will you get new concrete in? Wheelbarrow? Pumping? Do you know if there is any plumbing buried in that concrete? Is the concrete rebar and/or rewire reinforced?  Perhaps this is "A strange game. The only winning move is not to play. How about a nice game of chess?"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This may be too opinion-based for our format, but let's see what answers you get. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Yes I’d probably be inclined to agree with the chess comment. Maybe a small ramp being left in is my best option. Thank you for the replies nonetheless, I will take the tour. Best regards.

Comment: Professor Branestawm suggests removing the ramp and putting in a large platform with hydraulic lifter to act as a mini-elevator :-) .